# How to enable front camera in Phonegap

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova, camera

Opening webcam on a website using HTML5 & Js with the following code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="headBoxingStyle.css"/>
  </head>
  <body style="overflow: hidden">
    <div id="headtrack"></div>
    <canvas id='canvas' width='100' height='100'></canvas>
    <video width="100" height="100"></video>
  </body>
</html>

<script type="text/javascript">
var onFailSoHard = function(e)
{
    console.log('failed',e);
}

window.URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia ||  navigator.webkitGetUserMedia;

var video = document.querySelector('video');

if(navigator.getUserMedia)
{
  navigator.getUserMedia({video: true},function(stream) {
    video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
  }, onFailSoHard);
}

document.getElementById('snapshot').onclick = function() { 
  var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'); 
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'); 
  ctx.drawImage(video,0,0); 
} 
</script>
```

But how do you open device front camera via Phonegap. No pictures or video recorder is going to be taken but just display the front camera view. At the moment Phonegap camera plugin is installed, permissions are added and tested the example code on Phonegap that works fine but the code above only shows a Play symbol like in the picture.

**Here are the permissions**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.front" android:required="false" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

[image: Image that shows on device with the above code]

Phonegap version 3.1.0 API

Comment: Which plugin API you are using? Capture or media?

Comment: Phonegap version 3.1.0

Answer (score 6):

As per the Phonegap [documentation](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_camera_camera.md.html), you can specify which camera to open or provide a button to switch between front and back camera hardware

```
navigator.camera.getPicture( cameraSuccess, cameraError, [ cameraOptions ] );
```

here `cameraOptions` have many attributes, but what you need is Camera Direction

```
 {cameraDirection:1};
```

Where

```
Camera.Direction = {
    BACK : 0,      // Use the back-facing camera
    FRONT : 1      // Use the front-facing camera
};
```

Comment: where are you initializing the camera? These are the params which has to be passed to `getPicture` method in order to open front camera.

Comment: [The documentation also says that Android ignores this flag and always uses the back cam.](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera#android-quirks-1) Any solution for Android?

Comment: You can always write your own native module for phonegap, and most the the time this thing works, that's why it's called *"quirks"*

Comment: The above code doesn't work for me on my Samsung Galaxy S5.

Comment: it has been two years since the answer posted. off course, they have changed something in the SDK.

Answer (score 3):

On Cordova (formerly PhoneGap), you can't get the image via `navigator.getUserMedia` (as far as I know and neither was I able to find it from the Camera plugins source JavaScript). Instead you need to use the [Camera plugins API](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera/blob/master/doc/index.md). With that you use camera to retrieve a image as follows (from the documentation of the plugin)

```
navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail, { 
  destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI
  cameraDirection: Camera.Direction.FRONT // or Camera.Direction.BACK for back camera
});

function onSuccess(imageURI) {
  var image = document.getElementById('myImage');
  image.src = imageURI;
}

function onFail(message) {
  alert('Failed because: ' + message);
}
```

where parameter *destinationType* is used to determine whether the the success callback is called with Base64 encoded data or with URI of the image. As there is also stated in the [options section](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera/blob/master/doc/index.md#options), you can select the camera direction with *cameraDirection* option as shown in example.

**However**, you should notice that the Camera plugin tells in its [*Android quirks*](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera/blob/master/doc/index.md#android-quirks-1) that

> Any cameraDirection value results in a back-facing photo.

So unfortunately with this plugin, it isn't possible to programmatically set the camera to be the front one.

Comment: How would you implement this in the above code? No picture or video recording is needed just to open front camera

Comment: I disagree with this. getusermedia works just fine in IOS using cordova. It also runs ok on android providing you deploy with crosswalk.

Comment: @Lee2808 I don't think there was mention about Crosswalk being used by questioner and question was about Android? Crosswalk isn't used by default and there are cases where it isn't suitable so it shouldn't be assumed to be used.

Comment: @RoopeHakulinen agree there was no mention of crosswalk - I personally can't see a use-case other than needing to run on (really)low-spec devices where you wouldn't use it though. I made the comment for future readers, if they don't want to use the camera plugin on android then there is an alternative on android that works. My wording was too strong in response to your answer granted!

Answer (score 0):

@RoopeHakulinen : I have used getusermedia in Cordova android apps without using Crosswalk too. I had too add the following in my config.xml though, in order for camera permissions to work.

```
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" in the widget tag.
```

and then

```
<config-file mode="merge" parent="/*" target="app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml">
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
        <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
        <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />           
</config-file>
```

I also used permissions plugin, to authorize camera permission in the begining (on launch) itself instead of asking for permission later.

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-android-permissions" spec="^1.0.0" />
```

Answer (score -1):

- List item

Set this for ANDROID :

```
(in app/res/xml/config.xml)
<feature name="Camera">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.camera.CameraLauncher" />
</feature>


(in app/AndroidManifest)
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail, { quality: 50, cameraDirection:1, destinationType:        destinationType.DATA_URL}); }
```

- onSuccess :`function cameraCallback(imageData) {
  var image = document.getElementById('myImage');
  image.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
  }`
- Camera direction :

  Camera.Direction = {
      BACK : 0,      // Use the back-facing camera
      FRONT : 1      // Use the front-facing camera
  };